# Quickblox Android sdk 2.0 Beta some classes missing

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, quickblox

I am using QuickBlox android sdk 2.0 Beta and using sample chat app for reference.

But some classes used in app are not found in the sdk.

These classes are:

com.quickblox.module.chat.listeners.SessionListener ,

com.quickblox.module.chat.listeners.RoomListener,

com.quickblox.module.chat.listeners.ChatMessageListener,

com.quickblox.module.chat.utils.QBChatUtils ,

com.quickblox.module.chat.QBChatRoom and

com.quickblox.module.chat.smack.SmackAndroid etc.

Can someone provide the sdk with all classes or I have to wait for new sdk release.
Is there any specific time for new sdk release?

Comment: Chat sample is updated to SDK 2.0 Use this brunch and post your feedback to the github issues page https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/new_api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickblox Chat 2.0 is out now. Prefer WebRTC based SDK

Answer (score 1):

According to changes in SDK most of this classes were removed. You can start work with new chat after reading this:

1. chat sample
   https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/new_api/sample-chat
2. or snippets
   :https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/blob/new_api/snippets/src/com/quickblox/snippets/modules/SnippetsChat.java.
3. Or you can find information how to integrate new chat reading
   article about Chat2.0 feature
   :http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#SDK.

Tha main changes are:

- SessionListener was removed and replaced with
  QBEntittyCalbback when you invoke login method. In addition to this
  ConnectionListener was added to handle errors with connection during
  connection session.
- RoomListener was removed cause it became    uneccessary. To listen
  successfull result on creating or joining room    you can use
  QBEntittyCallback or do this operations synchronous.
- ChatMessageListener was removed and replaced with QBMessageListener 
  on particular chat: QBPrivateChat or QBRoomChat.
- QBChatRoom renamed to QBRoomChat.
- classes like SmackAndroid aren't necessary more. All necessary initializations are   invoked now in QBChatService class via init() and etc methods.
- QBChatUtils was renamed to Utils and removed to com.quickblox.module.chat.utils package.